# Получение картинки с веб камеры

Tags: c#, dll, web-camera

Подскажете библиотеку для работы с изображением веб камеры C#.
Пожалуйста приведите примеры кода или статьи уроков по работе с библиотекой.

Comment: Можно использовать библиотеку WIA.

Comment: Могу сказать только, что делал скрипт на vbs для фото, подправив чуть скрипт сканирования с сканера (из интернета). Проблем с deviceid не встретил, есть отдельно библиотека позволяющая прошерстить все устройства, а так же есть WMI. Возможно этот https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431202/using-a-scanner-without-dialogs-in-c-sharp можно чуть переделать код.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел код в несколько строк.

```
using Emgu.CV;

Capture capture = new Capture(); //create a camera captue
Bitmap image = capture.QueryFrame().Bitmap; //take a picture
pictureBox.Image = image;
```