# Что посоветуете для захвата видео с вебкамеры?

Tags: c#, c++, видео, видеодрайвера

В моём проекте требуется реализация захвата видео с вебкамеры. Какую библиотеку либо WinApi посоветуете для этого использовать?

Проект на C#. Допустимо написание dll на C++.

Пользователю должны быть предоставлены следующие возможности:

- Выбор устройства видеозахвата (список полных имён устройств)
- Следующие настойки видеодрайвера: яркость, контрастность, оттенок, насыщенность, чёткость, гамма, баланс белого, съёмка против света, цветность, масштаб, фокус, выдержка, диафрагма, сдвиг, наклон, разворот, компенсация низкой освещённости.
- Определение какие из всех настроек возможны для данного устройства

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/682830/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B вот тут я задавал похожий вопрос, с помощью данной библиотеки можно получить не только изображение, но и видео. Не нужно опзновать устройство.

Comment: Что значит не нужно опознавать устройство? А мне нужно. Я хочу не с дефолтного может записывать. В документации последней версии Emgu CV класса `Emgu.CV.Capture` я что-то не вижу (http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.2.0/document/html/b72c032d-59ae-c36f-5e00-12f8d621dfb8.htm). Есть класс `VideoCapture`. [Настройки](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.2.0/document/html/766b735b-77fa-f092-3d40-21545a7d0d8f.htm) вроде как позволительны. Так это просто известный Open CV, только для .NET переделанный. Хм. Даже и не слышал о таком)

Comment: Как вообще можно здесь перечислять устройства видеозахвата? Вообще такого найти не могу. Не может быть, чтобы это не было реализовано!

Comment: [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com)

Comment: Этот вариант я рассматривал. Только и трети настроек для видеодрайвера библиотека не предоставляет...

Comment: [4 настройки](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/). Смехотворно...

Comment: Или вы всмысле хотите предложить ещё одну библиотеку просто для перечисления устройств? Что за ерунда. Не жирно ли будет?..